# RDC app not working on Win 8 works fine on Win 7

Tags: c#, windows, service, remote-desktop

I wrote an app in C# WPF and VS2012 that uses the RDC control (AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7) to connect to a remote server.

The app has been working perfectly in Win 7 but when I installed it on a Windows 8 machine, as soon as it connects to the remote server it disconnects by itself. All we can see is a blink of the app main screen.

I checked the IMsTscAxEvents_OnDisconnectedEvent and the error code returned = 1
According to the table it says {1, "Local disconnection. This is not an error code."},

I tried to run in Win 7 compatible mode but nothing changed.

I have tested it in 2 different Win 8 boxes on sepatated locations and the problem is the same. In all Win 7 it works without a problem.

In the Win 8 machine, if I try to connect manually, using the same credentials of the app and the RDC control that come with the OS, it works as expected without dropping the connection. Could it be that the AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7 that I'm using in the app is not supported in Win 8 ?

Does anybody knows anything about this? At the moment I have no idea on what path to go.

Here is the code. The RDC control is hosted on a forms user control

// This line is execute somewhere else. Placed here only for reference.
private AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7 rdc;

```
       public void ConnectToServer(string UserName, string Password, string ServerIP)
        {
            int portNumber = 3389; // 5306  
            try
            {
                if (ServerIP.Contains(":"))
                {
                    portNumber = Convert.ToInt16(ServerIP.Substring(ServerIP.IndexOf(":") + 1, 4));
                    rdc.Server = ServerIP.Remove(ServerIP.IndexOf(":"));
                }
                else
                {
                    rdc.Server = ServerIP;
                }
                rdc.UserName = UserName;
                rdc.AdvancedSettings7.RDPPort = portNumber;
                rdc.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectPrinters = true;
                rdc.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectClipboard = true;
                rdc.AdvancedSettings7.RedirectSmartCards = true;
                rdc.AdvancedSettings7.AuthenticationLevel = 2;

                IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)rdc.GetOcx();
                secured.ClearTextPassword = Password;
                rdc.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error connecting to gateway server" + "\n Error:  " + Ex.Message, "Error Connecting", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the dll registered on the new computer? I had a similar issue all I had to do was to re-register `mstscax.dll` dll.

Comment: I re-registered the DLL but it is still the same.